# Windows installer from qt framework installer fails to run in jenkins pipeline

Tags: windows, qt, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have an application which installator was made by Qt Framework Installer. I made jenkins pipeline where I wanted to run this installer file. On Windows 10 I am getting however exit 1 status and application is not installed. On the linux system I easily install it by jenkins pipeline.
Here is my code

```
    stage('Install test'){ 
        echo "Instalation..."
        bat("${installer_file} silent=1 skipAdminOperations=1")
    }
```

Where `skipAdminOperations` is my custom flag. When I run it on the node it is working. When I added `--verbose` flag to comannd it installed application on jenkins installer but stucked in the command line at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. If you have similar problem you need to add `@START /wait` before your command